# Flutter error : Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'. (problem in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml )

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

[I'm facing this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aipGC.png)

[Here is my AndroidManifest.xml code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXZjx.png)

Comment: Hi, you can embed images and copy&paste + format code snippets to make your question more readable for others. Take the effort to present your problems in an appealing way, find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from the **activity** tag:

```
android:name="flutterEmbedding"
```

Which is at Line 24 according to the screenshot you attached.